# error: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath

Tags: binding, datagrid

my xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="pRCPROFDataGrid"
                                              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
                                              CanUserAddRows="True"
                                              FlowDirection="RightToLeft" RowEditEnding="pRCPROFDataGrid_RowEditEnding"/>
```

my code c#:

```
DataTable tbl = lib.GetDataFromTable("SELECT column_name, data_type, nullable FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = '" + _table + "' order by column_id", "Usr");
        DataTable sourceTable = new DataTable();
        string[] _label = lib.GetDetailsTable(_table);

for (int element = 0; element <= tbl.Rows.Count - 1; element++)
        {
            DataGridBoundColumn _xtemp = null;
            if (tbl.Rows[element][1].ToString() == "bit")
            {
                _xtemp = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            }
            else
            {
                _xtemp = new DataGridTextColumn();
            }

            _xtemp.Header = _label[element];
            _xtemp.Binding = new Binding(tbl.Rows[element][0].ToString());
            _grid.Columns.Add(_xtemp);
            if (element == 0)
                _xtemp.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            if (element == 1)
                _xtemp.Width = new DataGridLength(1,    DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        }

_grid.ItemsSource = sourceTable.DefaultView;
```

the result:

Additional information: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Additional information: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Solved same problem by removing slash from column header (name).